# Spring Batch - gridSize

Tags: spring-batch

I want some clear picture in this.

I have 2000 records but I limit 1000 records in the master for partitioning using rownum with gridSize=250 and partition across 5 slaves running in 10 machines.

I assume 1000/250= 4 steps will be created.

1. Whether data info sent to 4 slaves leaving 1 slave idle? If number
   of steps is more than the number of slave java process, I assume the
   data would be eventually distributed across all slaves.
2. Once all steps completed, would the slave java process memory is
   freed (all objects are freed from memory as the step exists)?
3. If all steps completed for 1000/250=4 steps, to process the
   remaining 1000 records, how can I start my new job instance without
   scheduler triggers the job.

Comment: Show your partitioner code.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have not shown your `Partitioner` code, I would try to answer only on assumptions.

You don't have to assume about number of steps ( **I assume 1000/250= 4 steps will be created** ), it would be number of entries you create in `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,ExecutionContext>` that you return from your `partition` method of [Partitioner Interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html).

`partition` method takes `gridSize` as argument and its up to you to make use of this parameter or not so if you decide to do partitioning based on some other parameter ( instead of evenly distributing count ) then you can do that. Eventually, number of partitions would be number of entries in returned map and values stored in `ExecutionContext` can be used for fetching data in readers and so on.

Next, you can choose about number of steps to be started in parallel by setting appropriate `TaskExecutor` and `concurrencyLimit` values i.e. you might create 100 steps in `partition` but want to start only 4 steps in parallel and that can very well be achieved by configuration settings on top of partitioner.

**Answer#1:** As already pointed, data distribution has to be coded by you in your reader using `ExecutionContext` information you created in partitioner. It doesn't happen automatically.

**Answer#2:** Not sure what you exactly mean but yes, everything gets freed after completion and information is saved in meta data.

**Answer#3:** As already pointed out, all steps would be created in one go for all the data. Which steps run for which data and how many run in parallel can be controlled by readers and configuration.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks. Gary/Anyone, Could you help me on triggering a job (java process) by another java process. I am able to trigger & could see the java process in task manager but I am not seeing the job running in job repository (database). Please help me

Comment: I have a message sent to a Channel. How can I use jmsTemplate to send to a destination queue.                              channal name:              <int:channel id="requestsChannel"/>                                                     jms outbound: <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter  connection-factory="connectionFactory"
       channel="requestsChannel"           destination name="requestsQueue"/>